# How to generate n theano.shared variables for Gaussian mixture regression?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, python, gaussian-mixture-distribution, theano

I am trying to program a Gaussian mixture regression using python, and the theano package.  Suppose I have n clusters, then I need to generate n regression weight matrices for each cluster (also, n error variances, and cluster probabilities).  In theano framework, I need to generate n shared variables for the regression weight matrices.  My intuition tells me that I should dynamically create variables using loop, but I also heard this is bad practice.  So, what is the recommended way to do this? Is there any example code I can learn from? Thanks.